# How to change the GPS settings in Android programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to change the GPS settings of an app by clicking the **Accept** button. But I can't find any reference on how to do that? I tried but security exception occurred. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));`
You can use this

Comment: I did change the settings using the above intent, but when i come back to my appl, then the changes are not reflected, it again asks to navigate to the setttings to enable the gps

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what exactly you're trying to achieve ? @SamarthKejriwal

Answer (score 0):

Android Guidelines have changed above version 4.0. You cannot change GPS off on programmatically for versions above 4.0.

Apps cannot enable or disable GPS programmatically, except perhaps on rooted devices. Please allow the user to do that.
I suggest you to use dialog for asking user to turn off and on the gps, and redirect to settings on ok button press.that is even better and user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution, using GoogleApiClient we can enable the GPS by providing priority programmatically with out moving user to the settings page.